# Basic properties of integrals on f(x)

Tags: calculus

Given:

$$\int_0^2 f(x)dx = 6$$
$$\int_2^5 f(x)dx = -8$$

$f(x)\geq0 \forall x\in[0,2]$ and $f(x)\leq0 \forall x\in[2,5]$.

Comment on the following integrals.

a.$\int_0^5 f(x)dx$

$$\int_0^2 f(x)dx + \int_2^5 f(x)dx = \int_0^5 f(x)dx$$

6 + (-8) = -2

b. $\int_0^5 |f(x)|dx$

Since the answer for a is supposedly -2, would it simply be 2?

c.$\int_2^5 4|f(x)|dx$

$$\int_0^2 4|f(x)|dx = 4\int_0^2 |f(x)|dx = 4 * 8 = 32$$

d.$\int_0^5 (f(x) + |f(x)|)dx$

The last one is a little tricky, I'm not sure where to start. Again, sorry for the mistakes before.

Comment: What have you tried? What properties of integrals are you already familiar with?

Comment: please show your work up to where you get stuck.

Comment: First off, I'm sorry for not writing the math properly, (so I'm not sure I'll be able to write them here haha) but I understand the basic five theorems. I see now that the first problem is the (a to c), (c to b) sum theorem, with the final answer being the sum of the two adding up to a to b. I was just expecting it to be (a to b) + (b to c) =(a to c)

Comment: Sorry, just added the work

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea with part (a). For part (b), it helps to think of it this way:
$$
\int_0 ^5 |f(x)| \, dx 
= \int_0 ^2 |f(x)| \, dx + \int_2 ^5 |f(x)| \, dx
$$
Now, we know that $f$ is positive on $[0,2]$, and $f$ is negative on $[2,5]$ (which, incidentally tells us that $f(2) = 0$, though that is besides the point). So,$$
\int_0 ^5 |f(x)| \, dx 
= \int_0 ^2 |f(x)| \, dx + \int_2 ^5 |f(x)| \, dx
= \int_0 ^2 f(x) \, dx + \int_2 ^5 -f(x) \, dx
= 6 - (-8) = 14.
$$
From this, I imagine you can get (c) now. As for (d), just use parts (a) and (b), as 
$$
\int_0 ^5 (f(x) + |f(x)|) \, dx 
= \int_0 ^5 f(x) \, dx + \int_0 ^5 |f(x)| \, dx .
$$